# Remote access to a windows XP Embedded system running a Java based HMI Screen

Tags: networking, windows-xp, remote-desktop, java, embedded

What options are available to me to be able to get remote access to a Windows XP Embedded machine that is being used as a machine interface (HMI, GUI) the HMI is running a Java based software and I would like to be able to temporarily view what is on the screen from a remote location on its network, the network is a local machine network with only two items on it, I can plug into the local network

The machine has a fixed IP address

As all our machines are XP embedded we cant get them connected to the customers network, but whilst on site it would be good to be able to see the HMI from my laptop anywhere on the machine

I would like to be able to connect using a windows 7 laptop

At the moment we have to remove the HMI PC and configure our laptops with the same IP address then with the HMI software installed on our laptops we have remote access, but this takes time and cant be done whilst the machine is in use as production do not have access to the controls

Comment: Does this embedded XP implementation support remote desktop? Try Control Panel -> System -> Remote page -> "Remote Desktop" section -> "Allow users to connect remotely to this computer"

Answer (score 0):

A few options, as per @jdh one is Remote Desktop  aka Terminal Services; http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281311

> All versions of Microsoft Windows XP include the Terminal Services
>   service.

Or a third party app such as [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/) may do